# Can we add major and Minor information manually in wsdl for WCF service

Tags: wcf, web-services, configuration

Can we add major and Minor information 
manually in wsdl for WCF service.We are calling in a third party 
service and they are versioning their service and want us to
include the major and minor version in the wsdl that they provided.
so i am not sure can we add those information manualy.

Comment: What do you mean, major and minor information? Do you mean major version information and minor version information? What do you expect that a client will do with this information?

Comment: We are calling in a third party service and they are versioning their service and want us to include the major and minor version in the wsdl that they provided. so i am not sure can we add those information manualy.

Comment: How to generate contracts with wsdl?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Where would this information be included, and why haven't they told you how to do it, since they're the ones asking you to do it?